# How to know CocoaPods are installed or not? in out MAC?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

How can we know cocoapods are installed or not? in our MAC? While installing I am getting this out put in terminal:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
>       undefined method `ord' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type "pod" command in the terminal, if it will show this kind of out put, then can get confirmed that, pod is installed in your MAC

**Out put** of pod command in terminal :

[image]

Comment: using $ "pod " Command getting this          -bash: pod: command not found

Comment: So it is confirmed that pod is not installed in your Mac. Install it

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6

sudo gem install cocoapods
```

try these

Comment: "sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6"    Fetching: activesupport-4.2.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-4.2.6
Parsing documentation for activesupport-4.2.6
unable to convert "\x84" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/active_support/values/unicode_tables.dat, skipping
Installing ri documentation for activesupport-4.2.6
1 gem installed
                          getting this ok